# how to select multiple distinct columns from a partitioned table in DolphinDB database

Tags: join, dolphindb

I have a partitioned table in DolphinDB database. Two of the columns are symbol and name. Each symbol corresponds to a unique name. I need to select distinct symbol and name from the partitioned table.

I used the following script

```
t0 = select distinct(Symbol) as Symbol from t order by Symbol
t0 = select Symbol, Name from lj(t0, t, `Symbol)
```

but got the following error message:

```
execution was completed with exception
A regular left table can't perform left join (lj), sorted left join (slj), full join (fj), asof join (aj), or window join (pwj, wj) with another distributed or segmented table.
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can get around the problem with equal join. In DolphinDB equal join can be conducted between a regular table and a partitioned table.

```
t0 = select distinct(Symbol) as Symbol from t order by Symbol
t0 = select Symbol, Name from ej(t0, t, `Symbol)
t0 = select * from t0 where prev(Symbol) ne Symbol
```